# Как протестировать код одного класса не разгребая все +100500 ошибок во всём проекте

Tags: android, android-studio

Проект - порт не Андроид приложения. Естественно весь код красный. Переписал несколько классов и на одном появились сомнения. Хотелось бы протестить его код, что бы потом не вспоминать где это было. Попробовал JUnit-тестом, но он дёргает грэдл, а тот пережёвывает весь проект и валится из-за ошибок. Не пойму как заставить его запустить этот тест.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос добавлением в игнор всех проблеммных пакетов через sourceSets:

```
    sourceSets {
        main.java.exclude(
                'com/exemple/**',
                'ru/exemple/**',
                'etc/**'
        )
    }
```

Так отладку и тестирование можно делать обычным способом.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь что ваши тесты лежат в дефолтной папке: `".../test"`

откройте консоль, в студии внизу вкладка `"Terminal"`

Вставьте и запустите тесты:

```
./gradlew test -x compileReleaseJavaWithJavac -x compileDebugJavaWithJavac
```

по факту это запуск локальных Unit тестов игнорируя Javac компилятор, для двух типов сборки. Должно получится что-то типо в консоле:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s

После этого грэдлятина сложит их в папку:

> project/myapp/build/reports/tests/

Там есть и xml и html:
Выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не прокатывает, да оно и логично - если мы пропускаем javac, файл.java не компилируется в .class и выполнять нечего. Но Вы мне напомнили про консоль... javac... Hello World! ))) Наверное проще по старинке скомпилировать класс в консоли и запустить.

Comment: только проверил все работает, какая ошибка у вас? Да и кстати и не логично. Просто вы хотите тестировать участок кода, в котором есть нескомпилированный участок, это теоретически невозможно. Получается что тест априори не пройден. Нужно убедится что у теста нет связанных участков нескомпилированного кода вот и всё. Да и кстати если получается, что вы не можете вынести класс и протестировать его отдельным модулем, это проблема архитектуры, вам ваще только функциональный тест поможет, unit вас не спасет

Comment: Вы проверили на рабочем проекте? А у меня куча ошибок компиляции. И мне нужно протестировать один класс - в нём ошибки исправлены и зависимостей от проблеммных классов нет. По сути мне нужно скомпилировать только этот класс и выполнить его код любым способом.

Comment: да я провреил на рабочем приложении, сделал пару ошибко в разных классах, у меня там пару функций тестируются, прошли тесты. Потом подменил данные у меня, тест все ассерты правильно показал, где и что какая ошибка и строка. все корректно

Comment: ну нужно смотреть на чем валится, возможно что у вас мб свои типы сборок в гредлятине есть, ну такогд их убрать надо оставьте один, и его игнорьте.

Comment: У Вас в кэше остались классы с последнего удачного билда, у меня ни одного удачного ещё не было и запуск из консоли валится на таске `:app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac`. Если его тоже добавить в игнор, то `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, но тест не выполняется. Я думаю надо шаманить с `sourceSets`, но пока не выходит

Comment: нет  у вас в тестах тогда ошибка, кеш тут совсем непричем. Ради интереса я даже проверил ещё раз, то что в ответе у меня 100% рабочий вариант. Специально разфигачил проект. 
Ещё раз убедитесь, что вы не стартуете другие таски грэдла, где запускаете Javac в тем местах где может ыть вызван RuntimeEx. 
Выше ответ 100% рабочий, всё остальное зависит от вашего внутреннего проекта и разных кейсов, там что угодно можеть быть, у вас же проект не собран в теории.

Comment: Проект стандартный (создан студией через new project...) добавлены только папки с сорцами - что там может быть сверхестественного?

Comment: =) ну расшарьте ссыль на проект, и тест который запустить нужно я уверен, быстрей будет. Обсуждать то что одному человеку видно а другому нет, как-то абстрактно очень нет?